# how can I make my main character interesting and not bland?

Tags: plot, characters

All my supporting characters are really cool and have their habits and problems and backstories but I just feel so lost when it comes to my main character.  She just seems to be floating around in the story, not doing anything that sets her apart.  She is a volleyball player who wants to get better but is on a lazy, not serious team.  I just don't know what to do with her?

Comment: Why don't you have habits, problems, and a backstory for your main character? Are you getting blocked or you just can't come up with anything?

Comment: with the side characters, my main character can observe them and watch them and eventually figure out their backstory or talk about their habits, but I'm just having trouble weaving into the story the main characters habits and a possible backstory.  She can't observe herself.

Comment: Of course she can. "Barbara walked into the gym, and my fingers turned nerveless. The ball fell. I turned my head to avoid another of her withering glances, but I couldn't help looking back. She was so beautiful! My whole chest constricted just hearing her laugh. The end of my ponytail fell into my mouth practically of its own accord." She has now observed her own crush and nervousness, plus her habit of chewing on her hair, and given us some backstory on her sexuality.

Comment: omg you're right.  Okay thank you so much!  I know what to do now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always found it useful to answer a few questions about the character like I'm interviewing them.  Imagine what they would say and how they would respond.  Maybe you'll learn a little bit about them.

What are your MC's passions?  You said she is a volleyball player, what motivates her to play?  Does she find it fun or is there some deep story behind that?  Did her father/mother play?  Is she trying to be better than her older sister?

What other hobbies does your character have?

What are some flaws?  Is she too talkative, bubbly, quiet, shy/awkward, confident, etc.

You said your MC doesn't do anything to set her apart.  MAKE her stand out.  Make her interesting.

However, the MC will automatically connect more with the reader since we're seeing the story through their eyes, so even if your MC isn't super interesting or unique, it's not a *huge* problem.